# Uncaught TypeError: r(...).connect is not a function - Webpack - MQTT protocol

Tags: html, node.js, webpack

I'm using NodeJS and I have to get information from a TTN server via a MQTT protocol and then display it on a website. As 'require' is not recognized by browsers, I had to use browserify or webpack and I chose webpack because browserify was giving me errors at every step. I succeed to make 'require' getting understoog by browsers however I can't use methods of the package required. It throws an error that can change depending of how I'm asking my client to connect to the MQTT but the main part of the error is still the same. "e(...).connect is not a function" or "r(...).connect is not a function"

I have no idea of what else I can do about it so I didn't really tried to change something. The only thing I know is that the code is perfectly working when I run the index.js file alone with `node index.js` so I'm sure that every parameters are good. Also, I've tried, before using this method, to include `MQTT.js` directly in my html file by putting a  tag which worked but not completely, mqtt was recognized I don't really know why, mqtt started to use Websocket, probably to make nodeJS work on the browser but if I use Websocket, I can't connect to the TTN server because it has only one port to connect which is the 1883 one.

Here's my index.js file

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt')

const host = 'eu1.cloud.thethings.network'
const port = '1883'
const pyCard_id = 'ID_CARD'

const clientId = `mqtt_${Math.random().toString(16).slice(3)}`

const connectUrl = `mqtt://${host}:${port}`

mqtt.connect('connectURL')
```

My webpack.config.js file

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
};
```

And my .html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    <script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```